# Sending secure HTTP Post via javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, http, post

the issue I have ran into here is regarding trying to send HTTP POST data securely (without anyone using a HTTP header viewer to see what data variables are being passed over?)

Is this possible?

This is the scenario:

Website A provides a 'free online database' - for all site users who don't understand or want to set up a database on their website.

Website B uses website A's service to send over customer's email addresses.

Website B needs to send POST data to Website A with a special 'APIkey' - This can't be shown to the public, else the public can use the APIkey and spam requests which Website B didn't authorise.

How can this be achieved, without using PHP on Website B? I'd prefer it to be as easy as possible (e.g. a javascript plugin) - but would I be able to secure it so visitors of website B couldn't see what POST data was being sent over?

Hope you understand and thank you in advance!

Comment: you want to use https, and it's really not recommended to use http if you want any security

Comment: @MarkoMackic - Would using HTTPS solve this straight away? All I need is one variable (APIKEY) to be hidden / not possible to be found out from viewing source or http header sniffer.

Comment: I don't know you maybe could do something with http, but https would solve this straight away :) but http solution includes some kind of server side scripting :)

Comment: You can't hide that key using javascript in the browser. The only secure way is to use a proxy on your server that has the key and transfers data to/from api

Comment: That will not prevent man-in-the-middle

Comment: It's very confusing - To try and put this in the simplest way:

Website A is awaiting a request - will only accept it once a request is sent to it (including: APIkey). If this APIkey exists = it will process a function.

Website B has a valid APIkey and is sending over a request - from a visitor clicking a button on their website which triggers to send it over.

The only thing is if the visitor on Website B is able to view source / sniff http headers - the APIkey field would be visible, right? (Then they could essentially copy the APIkey and use it themselves!)

Comment: That is exactly mitm attack

Comment: @MarkoMackic Aha I see. I've googled that now - so HTTPS will resolve and MITM attack won't be possible if I use HTTPS?

However that means Website A & Website B BOTH need to be using SSL, right? 

Would I be able to make a javascript plugin which sends a HTTP POST from Website A (no SSL) but send it to Website B's SSL site? Would that work?

Comment: you need it only where you need data to be safe

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is like trying to take a banana and to make an apple.

This is just a big security hole. And is a big NO NO. Sever side only. Do not ever trust the clients (web broswer)

Comment: This is best suited as comment!

Comment: Sorry about this. But I'm unable to comment on any post or answer other than my own post or answer.

Comment: You have to work a little bit to earn more reputations then you will be free to comment as you wish. I did not see that you had low reputation in the first place.

Comment: Its not a rep issue, but rather the android app. i'm on the website on my laptop and its the app which is lacking the feature or i've gained enough rep as of now. as well posts and comments can't be deleted from the android app.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

JavaScript as you describe it would be executed in the browser.
The browser is controlled by the user so there is no way you can hide the key used to sign the requests from a moderately skilled attacker.

As a side-note, using HTTPS would not help either. HTTPS would only help to hide the key from a 3rd party watching the communication. It would not prevent the user of the site from extracting the key from JS.

Comment: Are you able to think of any way this could be achieved however? JQuery, or some other language? 

I'm certain it would be possible if the website used PHP and sent a http request over that - but I want to make some sort of plugin/addon for all websites - intermediate websites which are basic html?

Comment: PHP runs on the server side. JavaScript runs on the user-side. Authentication must happen on the server and thus under control of the application. Client-side authentication cannot be secured. The issue you are fighting is a fundamental problem of information security unrelated to what language exactly you use. You can run JS on the server using something like nodeJS but your approach of a site-plugin that authenticates in local JS is doomed to fail no matter if you use JS, Flash or any other client-side language.